# How do I create a parameterized database update statement in Yii for an IN() clause?

Tags: php, pdo, yii2

I tried

```
$sql = "update ad_group_keyword set status = :status where google_id not in (:google_id)";
Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)
  ->bindValue(':status', Constants::DELETED)
  ->bindValue(':google_id', join(',',$googleIds), \PDO::PARAM_INT)
  ->execute();
```

but it turned the array of ids into one giant string, despite the `PDO::PARAM_INT`. I also tried

```
  ->bindValue(':google_id', $googleIds)
```

but it gave an `'Array to string conversion' in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php:172`. I ended up using

```
$sql = "update ad_group_keyword set status = :status where google_id not in (" . join(',',$googleIds) . ")";
```

Comment: The solution you ended up using opens you up to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use QueryBuilder for this function:

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand();
$result = $command->update( // create a update sql
     'ad_group_keyword',  // table
     ['status'=>1],  // update set
     ['NOT IN', 'google_id', [1,2,3]] // where
)->execute();
```

You can read the [\yii\db\Command::update() DOC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#update()-detail), and how to [set condition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail)

Comment: Nice. I wasn't sure of the syntax for `IN` with the `update()` function since there were no examples.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a `join` in there at that place.  That is where it is being turned into a string.  You want to iterate through your list of ids and `bindValue` each one to the variable in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to bind each of the array values individually. Something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE ad_group_keyword
        SET status = :status
        WHERE google_id NOT IN(%s)";

$bindValues = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($googleIds as $value)
{
    $bindValues[':googleId'.$i++] = $value;
}

$sql        = sprintf($sql, join(', ', array_keys($bindValues)));
$sqlCommand = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);
$sqlCommand->bindValue(':status', Constants::DELETED);

foreach ($bindValues as $key => $value)
{
    $sqlCommand->bindValue($key, $value, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$sqlCommand->execute();
```

However, I'm only basing this example on *your* code and I'd look into Yii's manual to see if there already isn't a method that does all of this work for you ... it shouldn't be that hard to safely execute an SQL query using `IN()`.

Comment: Wow seriously? You have to create a placeholder for each array value, then bind them individually? There is no way to bind a whole array at once? I checked the guide and reference, but it didn't provide any examples for `IN` clauses.

Comment: Well, databases don't have an 'array' datatype and even if they did, there would be other obstacles for that. So that's kind of natural, but also where frameworks come helpful ... :)