# How do you bind an array in Yii for createCommand in a NOT IN clause for arbitrary SQL?

Tags: php, yii2

How do you bind an array for an IN clause in arbitrary SQL using the `createCommand()` statement?

```
$sql = ...   "where campaign.id not in (:notThese) " ...
$campaignId = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)
  //->bindValue(':notThese', ...)
  ->queryScalar();
```

I'm using `createCommand()` because I'm using `group by` and `having`. This is similar to this question & answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753889/148844 but I was hoping for a more elegant way in Yii. That accepted answer is for updates. The other answer is awkward. [`createCommand()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html) doesn't seem to have any functions for `IN` clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some examples which i guess will help you:

```
$values=[4,1];

$campaignId = (new \yii\db\Query())->from('campaign')->where(['not in','campaign.id',$values])->groupBy(['groupcolumn'])->scalar();
//  SELECT * FROM `campaign` WHERE `campaign.id` NOT IN (4, 1) GROUP BY `groupcolumn`;

$campaignId = (new \yii\db\Query())->from('campaign')->groupBy(['groupcolumn'])->having(['not in','campaign.id',$values])->scalar();
//  SELECT * FROM `campaign` GROUP BY `groupcolumn` HAVING `campaign.id` NOT IN (4, 1) ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't quote the field names properly with `leftJoin()`: `leftJoin('ad_group', ['campaign.id' => 'ad_group.campaign_id'])` turns into `LEFT JOIN \`ad_group\` ON \`campaign\`.\`id\`='ad_group.campaign_id'` which is comparing a field with a string!

Comment: Ok I got it to work with `$campaignId = (new Query())->select(['campaign.id', 'count(*) as c'])
      ->from('campaign')
      ->leftJoin('ad_group', 'campaign.id = ad_group.campaign_id')
      ->where(['not in', 'campaign.id', $notThese])
      ->groupBy(['campaign.id'])
      ->having(['<', 'c', 20000])
      ->scalar();` and I didn't even have to check if the array was null! It's a bit more verbose than straight SQL but fairly elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the yii\db\Query to use such features

```
$campaignId = (new \yii\db\Query())->from('campaign')->where(['in','campaign.id',$values])->scalar();
```

Comment: Yeah, but did you see the part about using `group by` and `having` clauses? How would you write this with `Query()`? `select campaign.id, count(*) as c from campaign left join ad_group on campaign.id = ad_group.campaign_id where campaign.id not in (:notThese) group by campaign.id having c < 20000;`